# Python Scraping under tag text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My scenario is different in this case I want to **scrape** text from this kind of stuff but not knowing how to point it.

```
<td><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gl"></span>Greenland</td>
```

I don't know how to do a thing with that staff.

Comment: you want text `"Greenland"`!

Comment: yeah @HumayunAhmadRajib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it many ways.

Use **find** span tag and then **parent** tag and get **text**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<td><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gl"></span>Greenland</td>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.find("span",class_="flag-icon flag-icon-gl").parent.text)
```

---

Or use css selector and `next_element`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<td><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gl"></span>Greenland</td>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.select_one("td>.flag-icon.flag-icon-gl").next_element)
```